# create multiple shiny widgets with data from uploaded file

Tags: r, shiny

In `shiny`, how do you use `tagList` inside `renderUI` to create multiple widgets customized with data from an uploaded file?  This idea is referenced [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html), but there doesn't appear to be very good documentation for `tagList`.

I plan to answer my own question here.  I did a bit of research, found that a simple example of this process was lacking, and felt a desire to contribute it so that others might benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In server.R, define an object using a `reactive()` statement to hold the contents of the uploaded file.  Then, in a `renderUI` statement, wrap a comma-delimited list of widget definitions in a `tagList` function.  In each widget, use the object holding the contents of the uploaded file for the widget parameters.  The example below, [hosted at shinyapps.io](https://debarros.shinyapps.io/CSVtoChecklist/) and [available on github](https://github.com/debarros/CSVtoChecklist), creates a checkBoxGroupInput and a radioButtons widget using a singer renderUI that is defined based on an uploaded file.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

  ItemList = reactive(
    if(is.null(input$CheckListFile)){return()
    } else {d2 = read.csv(input$CheckListFile$datapath)
            return(as.character(d2[,1]))}
  )

  output$CustomCheckList <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(ItemList())){return ()
    } else tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "SelectItems", 
                         label = "Which items would you like to select?", 
                         choices = ItemList()),
      radioButtons("RadioItems", 
                   label = "Pick One",
                   choices = ItemList(), 
                   selected = 1)
    )
  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Create a checkboxGroupInput and a RadioButtons widget from a CSV"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(fileInput(inputId = "CheckListFile", label = "Upload list of options")),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("CustomCheckList")
    )
  )
))
```